# Update single field

Tags: django

I have a `Customer` class which has a `representative` field....this field is initially blank but when the user opens up the details page of the chosen customer, they'll be given the open of representing this customer by clicking on a link.  The template layout I was thinking of is this:

```
<strong>Representative: </strong>
{% if customer.representative %}
   {{ customer.representative }}
{% else %}
   <a href="{% url representCustomer customer.id %}">Represent this customer.</a>
{% endif %}
```

All that remains is the view to effect this...this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out customer from url and you can get current user from request, then it's merely two lines of view code:

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
customer.representative = Representative.objects.get(user=request.user)
customer.save()
```

That said, **changing** data by GET request is not recommended technique.

Comment: Ahhhh...thanks Dmitry.  This worked like a charm...I'll keep in mind the tip also.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the representative that the user belongs to and assign it to the `representative` field of the relevant customer model, then save.

Comment: how to do this is what is bothering me....yes I know the overall mechanism, but the actual implementation is still unknown to me...